# Arrange plots in knitr but keep them as vector graphics

Tags: r, plot, knitr, vector-graphics

I have two functions which create plots with ggplot and return them. The first plot is wide (two facets), the second is narrow. I want to place them below each other, to look like a square 2x2 grids, with the two facets on top and the small plot on the bottom left. And grid.arrange can place them in this configuration.

[image]

Now for the problem: I am creating a LaTeX document with knitr. So, my chunk uses `dev='pdf'` and I'm pretty much stuck with that (I can't, say, do a `ggsave` in a format of my choice). While all plots which I call directly in such a chunk are nice vector graphics, anything that I arrange with grid.arrange comes out rasterized, and at a dpi which doesn't look too good even on a computer screen. The documentation says that grid.arrange is supposed to print "using the current device" but it seems to include a rasterizing step.

Is there a way to change that, or am I stuck with pixelation when I use grid.arrange?

This is the chunk I am using:

```
<<relevance-pics, eval=TRUE, dev='pdf', fig.height=3, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
match.name <- "relevance"
grid.arrange(create.hist.comparison(match.name), change.in.matched.plot(match.name), layout_matrix=rbind(c(1,1),c(2,NA)))
@
```

Comment: It might be worth trying `cairo_pdf` for the device to see if that works better. You could also try `dev=c('pdf', 'svg')` to have it save the images as SVG as well and see if those avoid being rasterized.

Comment: OK, I tried Cairo, and also opened the graphic files themselves in Inkscape. It turns out that the grid.arrange graphics are not rasterized, they are vector, but they are rendered weirdly. For example, plot border of one facet gets rendered with 4 lines with different widths. Also, it does not use clipping, but "cuts off" invisible parts of objects (the blue points in the second graph) and they don't line up well with the covering objects. So the end image (both with Cairo and native pdf) is weird and looks bad in Okular. Images which did not go through grid.arrange don't have these problems.